# specs-esp8266 Missing From ESPDuino (ESP-13 Module)

Tags: c++

When I installed arduino-1.8.1 for linux mint 17 (fully updated and upgraded), the file specs-esp8266 was not included in any of the folders, and the compiler threw an error: "avr-g++: error: cannot access device-specs for 'esp8266' expected at '/opt/arduino-1.8.1/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/device-specs/specs-esp8266'". There are spec files there for lots of other boards (e.g. specs-avrtiny, specs-avrxmega7, specs-m3000, etc), but I've not been able to find this particular one. Help, please.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?